# Calcular descuento y precio total - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ejs

[![Carrito][1]][1]

Estoy realizando un proyecto de E-commerce. Necesito que una vez que se agregan los productos al carrito, calcular el valor de descuento (si es que lo tiene) y el valor total (dependiendo la cantidad)

Realice un input type="number" para que varie la cantidad.

Mi idea es hacer mediante JavaScript que si el usuario quiere cambiar esa cantidad mediante ese input, se calcule automaticamente el descuento y el total cuando va "clickeando"

Intente armar un codigo JS pero cuando varia la cantidad en el total me sale el error "NaN"

Archivo EJS

````
```<!--cantidad-->
                        <div class="col-1 d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <form class="cantidad_item rounded" action="cantidad_item" method="POST">
                            <small id="" class="form-text text-muted">Cantidad</small>
                            <div class="def-number-input number-input safari_only">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" style="width: 80px" id="cantidad" value="1" />
                            </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    <!--precio-->
                    <div class="col-1 justify-content-end">
                        <div class="price_item">
                            <div class="price_uni_item">
                                <small class="form-text text-muted">Precio</small>
                                <p class="cart-price price_tag_total p-2 rounded bg-transparent mb-0" style="width: 100px" id="precio"> <%= carrito[i].precioUnitario %></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <!--descuento-->
                    <div class="col-1 justify-content-end">
                        <div id="precio" class="price_item">
                        <div class="price_uni_item">
                            <small class="form-text text-muted">Descuento</small>
                            <p class="price_tag_total p-2 rounded bg-transparent mb-0" style="width: 100px" id="descuento">% <%= carrito[i].descuento %></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--total-->
                    <div class="col-1 justify-content-end">
                        <div id="precio" class="price_item">
                        <div class="price_uni_item">
                            <small class="form-text text-muted">Total</small>
                            <p class="cart-total-price price_tag_total p-2 rounded bg-transparent mb-0" style="width: 100px" id="total" ></p>
                            
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
````

```

Archivo JS

````
    var cantidad = document.getElementById("cantidad");
    cantidad.addEventListener("change", function(){

        var precioUnitario = document.getElementById("precio");
        console.log(typeof precioUnitario, typeof cantidad.value)
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = parseInt(cantidad.value) * precioUnitario.value;
    })  
        
}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xfjrr.png
````

Comment: Además de `parseInt()` usado para convertir el tipo `String` en un valor entero para el campo *cantidad*, podrías usar `parseFloat()` para hacer lo mismo con el campo *precioUnitario*. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Mauricio.
Me sigue dando el error NaN en el "total" cuando hago click para variar la cantidad. Probe agregando el parseFloat()

Comment: precioUnitario es un `element` de tipo `parrafo` no un `input` por ende no tiene un propiedad `value` y por eso devuelve `Nan` lo mas cercano es su propiedad `innerText`, por lo que deberia quedar asi: `parseFloat(precioUnitario.innerText)`... no obstante tu funcion te dara problemas ya que tomas el valor de `cantidad` antes del evento debes pasarle `function(e)` y `e.target.value` o `this.value` para que tome el valor luego del evento no antes!

Comment: Gracias Bryro por tu comentario. Me funciono pero tengo un problema: Al momento de agregar mas items al carrito de compras, el precio total solo me lo realize en 1 solo producto, een el resto no.
Deberia usar un For?